# how can I rewrite this code to make it easier to read?

Tags: python, pandas

```
start=2014
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':past_cars_sold,}, index = [start, start+1,start+2,start+3,start+4,start+5,start+6])
```

is there an easier way to rewrite this code. Right now i have do it one at a time and just want to know if there is an easier way to rewrite this.

Comment: You can use list comprehension to rewrite line 2 into: ```df = pd.DataFrame({'age':past_cars_sold,}, index = [start+x for x in range(0,7)])
```

Comment: Better yet, directly create the appropriate `range` object. It is a sequence, which is all Pandas needs; you don't need to make a `list`. That looks like: `df = pd.DataFrame({'age':past_cars_sold,}, index=range(x, x+7))`.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing a for loop will allow you to automatically populate the list with the values you want using simple math & logic.

```
start = 2014
index = []
for i in range(7):
   index.append(start+i)
```

This makes the code more readable, and also nearly infinitely scalable. You will also not have to populate your list manually.

Edit:
As others have added, you can use [Pythonic List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) as well.
This means you can populate a list in one line like so:

```
start = 2014
index = [start+i for i in range(7)] # from i=0 to i=6 (7 total elements)
```

Comment: Please use one liner pythonic list comprehension!

Comment: List comprehension is more idiomatic: `index = [start+i for i in range(7)]`

Answer (score 0):

First, write it like this, easier to read and reorgranize later

```
start=2014
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'age':past_cars_sold,
        }, 
    index = [
        start, 
        start+1,
        start+2,
        start+3,
        start+4,
        start+5,
        start+6
        ]
    )
```

Then, see if you can simplify it, for example

```
past_cars_sold = [1,2,3,4,5,6]          # dummy test values
start = 2014                            # avoid hard-coding value
years = 6                               # or group these values together
idxls = range(start, start + years, 1)  # form a list with  functions
```

replace it

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'age':past_cars_sold,
        }, 
    index = idxls
    )
```

maybe also a good idea to read the [official "Pythonic" way](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to format your code.